# Why there is a difference between Alfresco Node Browser and programmatical same query execution?

Tags: alfresco

I have the following query

```
(TYPE:"ecmcndintregst:nd_int_reg_standards" OR TYPE:"ecmcndcountryst:nd_country_standards") AND (=ecmcnddoc:doc_name_ru:"" OR =ecmcnddoc:doc_name_ru:"\-") AND (=ecmcnddoc:doc_kind_cp_ecmcdict_value:"standard_itu")
```

and it has different results in Alfresco NodeBrowser (fts-alfresco) and in Java code "solr-fts-alfresco" (both results should be < 1000 and they are)

```
    SearchParameters searchParameters = new SearchParameters();
    searchParameters.setLanguage(SearchService.LANGUAGE_SOLR_FTS_ALFRESCO);
    searchParameters.addStore(StoreRef.STORE_REF_WORKSPACE_SPACESSTORE);
    searchParameters.setLimitBy(LimitBy.UNLIMITED);
    searchParameters.setLimit(1000);
    searchParameters.setPermissionEvaluation(PermissionEvaluationMode.EAGER);
    searchParameters.addLocale(new Locale("ru", "RU"));
    searchParameters.setQuery(query);
    tempResultSet = customSearchService.query(searchParameters);
```

Also, in the Java code the clause `=ecmcnddoc:doc_name_ru:""`may fails two different ways: as always FALSE in query:

```
(TYPE:"ecmcndintregst:nd_int_reg_standards" OR TYPE:"ecmcndcountryst:nd_country_standards") AND (=ecmcnddoc:doc_name_ru:"" OR =ecmcnddoc:doc_name_ru:"\-") AND (=ecmcnddoc:doc_kind_cp_ecmcdict_value:"standard_itu")
```

And always TRUE in query:

```
(TYPE:"ecmcndintregst:nd_int_reg_standards" OR TYPE:"ecmcndcountryst:nd_country_standards") AND (=ecmcnddoc:doc_name_ru:"") AND (=ecmcnddoc:doc_kind_cp_ecmcdict_value:"standard_itu")
```

Could you tell me the proper way to use `=ecmcnddoc:doc_name_ru:""` clause?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking for results that have an empty "doc_name_ru", have you tried:

```
-EXISTS:"ecmcnddoc:doc_name_ru"
```